# Forcing bibliography order

Tags: bibtex, sorting

I've a bibliography which include websites. I want to have an alphabetical sort. Thus I use the plain style which do the job great. The problem is websites are less important than others references and I would like to put them at last.

Is it possible to force that?

Here is a part of the BibTex file :

```
@Misc{wikianglais,
title = {\url{http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack}},
month = {mai},
year = {2013}
}

@Book{Thorp,
author = {Edward O. Thorp},
ALTeditor = {},
title = {Beat the dealer},
publisher = {Vintage Books Edition},
year = {1966},
month = {février}
}

@Book{Braun,
author = {Julian H. Braun},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {How to play winning Blackjack},
publisher = {Data House Pub. Co},
year = {1980}
}
```

I would like to get : Braun, Thorp and then the Wikipedia reference but the actual order is : the Wikipedia reference, Braun, Thorp.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your bibliography?

Comment: there's n `unsrt` style that should set your bib items in the order in which they occur in your `.bib` file.  i'm not sure what is used for labels in the output.

Comment: `unsrt` sort the references in appearance order in the `.tex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a proper solution, but it works...

Add a "fake" `key` field

```
key = {zzzz}
```

in all your `@Misc` entries.

In this way the `key` field is used for sorting (and `zzzz` comes after all the other entries, I suppose), but it is not printed in the bibliography. BTW, I don't know any `ALTeditor` field.

So, changing your bibliography MWE to

```
@Misc{wikianglais,
key = {zzzz},
title = {\url{http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack}},
month = {mai},
year  = {2013}
}

@Book{Thorp,
author = {Edward O. Thorp},
ALTeditor = {},
title = {Beat the dealer},
publisher = {Vintage Books Edition},
year = {1966},
month = {février}
}

@Book{Braun,
author = {Julian H. Braun},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {How to play winning Blackjack},
publisher = {Data House Pub. Co},
year = {1980}
}
```

should be enough.

A MWE just to test it:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{wikianglais,
key = {zzzz},
title = {\url{http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack}},
month = {mai},
year  = {2013}
}

@Book{Thorp,
author = {Edward O. Thorp},
ALTeditor = {},
title = {Beat the dealer},
publisher = {Vintage Books Edition},
year = {1966},
month = {février}
}

@Book{Braun,
author = {Julian H. Braun},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {How to play winning Blackjack},
publisher = {Data House Pub. Co},
year = {1980}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{wikianglais} \cite{Thorp} \cite{Braun}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]